# Can this lead to rejection of iphone app

Tags: iphone

I am making an app and one of the requirements is a contactlist of people working in the company. I have made a tableview, searchbar and a detailedviewcontroller with view that shows details of a contact. The detail view is almost identical with the native contactview.

This can't lead to that my app is going to be rejected can it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think so, you’re not competing with the system Contacts app and UI consistency is good.